# How could I extend a format-spec for existing type (eg float) in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdformat

I want to extend formatting options for floating-point type, preferably preserving some of the existing options. For instance, I want to add a new `type` specifier for the measurements with units to write like this `std::format({:.5mm}, 0.05f)` and get my data printed with `precision=5`, but also multiplied by 1000 and prefixed with 'mm'. Is that even possible?

Comment: Why not use special type instead? `std::format("{:.5mm}", MyUnit(0.05f))`.

Comment: @Jarod42, It might be a problem when I have a container of floats which I also want to create a formatter for. As I see it, I'd have to convert container so that it stores another type (`MyUnit`) or create the aforementioned `type` specifier but for container only, which is not really consistent in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formatting specification for basic types like `float` are built into the system; you cannot extend them.

You *can* wrap them in a user-defined type which you can apply whatever formatting to you like. As exemplified in the comments, `std::format("{:.5mm}", MyUnit(0.05f))`, where `MyUnit` is your type which has its own formatting specification.

Comment: there's already [Boost.Units](https://github.com/boostorg/units) so if Boost is available it'll be a better idea than a custom class